# Specifying more than one class modifier

Tags: java

In [section 8.1.1 Class Modifiers of the Java Language Specification 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1), it states that:

> ClassModifier: one of
>       Annotation public protected private abstract static final strictfp

But I managed to compile the following:

```
public strictfp A{}
```

That is, it states that one of the class modifiers should be chosen but I was able to choose more than one. Am I misinterpreting the specification here?

Comment: did you read three lines before what you pasted? "A class declaration may include class modifiers. ClassModifiers:
    ClassModifier
    ClassModifiers ClassModifier"

Comment: I'm sure you meant java7, in java8 it doesn't state that

Comment: @msrd0 java 8 JLS doesnt have above line. Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1) So OP is reading SE 7's JLS and assuming its for 8.

Comment: @almasshaikh I know, I read that and thats why I think the OP means Java7

Comment: It does have that line in the pdf version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in the rule above:

```
ClassModifiers:
    ClassModifier
    ClassModifiers ClassModifier <<== Here

ClassModifier: one of
    Annotation public protected private abstract static final strictfp
```

Essentially, the rule says that you can use one or more `ClassModifier`s in a `ClassModifiers` list. This recursive definition of an iterative concept of "one or more" is common for BNF-style syntax descriptions (as opposed to EBNF, that provide a special syntax for repetitions).

Comment: Sorry I need more explanation. If I look at the NormalClassDeclaration, it states {ClassModifier} not ClassModifers (ie the plural). Please explain how I should read that.

Comment: @I.K. `{` <something> `}` means "Zero or more repetitions of <something>". This is EBNF style. Square brackets `[` <something> `]` mean "optional <something>". It is strange that the they mix the two styles, though.

Answer (score 5):

The [ClassModifiers Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1) tells exactly :

```
ClassModifiers:
    ClassModifier
    ClassModifiers ClassModifier

ClassModifier: one of
    Annotation public protected private
    abstract static final strictfp
```

So it is either 1 or more ClassModifier before the class